# Xamarin form bind a specific row to code

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

basically i want to bind a specific row to a grid in the .cs files is it possible ??

Here is the schematics

```
<Grid x:Name="grid1">
<Grid.RowDefinition>
<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
<RowDefinition Height="Auto" /><!-- want to bind this row to a grid made in c# -->
<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
</Grid.RowDefinition>

</Grid>
```

Comment: the code here creates 3 rows of equal size. What you want to do exactly?

Comment: the second row i want to bid it to a grid C# made . this grid contains a stack layout witch component are created dynamically from a db

Comment: couldnt understand your requirement though but a grid row can have your stack panel.....something like this... on your stackpanel add this Grid.Row="1" so that the stack panel moves into the second row

Comment: yes in the xaml file but can i do the same in the c# file specify the row in the c# . something like

Comment: yeah you can do that ! check the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Create an object of your stackPanel programatically. Make sure your stackpanel //has a name
StackPanel MyStackPanel = new StackPanel ();
StackPanel .Name= "stackPanel1";

Grid.SetRow(MyStackPanel , 1); 
Grid.SetColumn(MyStackPanel , 0);  // for setting it to 1st column
grid1.Children.Add(MyStackPanel );
```